# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD for register users. - LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Hi guys I saw many times this problem and I solved it but this time I cant see where is the problem, I have been blocked for several days, so I would like someone more experienced to help me, I await your response and thank you very much in advance.

A week ago I could register users without problems, but then they cant get loged (idk why), now they cant even register.

Route:

```
Route::get('/registerCreate', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'create'])->name('register.create');
Route::get('/registerStore', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'store'])->name('register.store.usu');
```

Controller:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Usuario;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function index()
    {

        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'nombre' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
            'apellido' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:50', 'unique:users'],
            'telefono' => ['required', 'string', 'number', 'max:9', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'nacionalidad' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\Usuario
     */

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return Usuario::create([
            'nombre' => $data['nombre'],
            'apellido' => $data['apellido'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'telefono' => $data['telefono'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'nacionalidad' => $data['nacionalidad'],

        ]);
    }



    public function store()
    {

        $usuario = Usuario::create(request([
            'nombre',
            'email',
            'password' => Hash::make('password'),
            'telefono',
            'email',
            'nacionalidad',


        ]));
        auth()->login($usuario);
        return redirect()->to('/login');
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<body class="body">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-center h5 py-4" style="font-weight:600">Registrate en Chani</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{ route('register.store.usu') }}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                @if($message = Session::get('ErrorInsert'))
                                <div class="col-12 alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade show" role="alert">
                                    <h5>Errores:</h5>
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li>{{$error}}</li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                @endif
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                                    @error('nombre')
                                    <p class="border border-red-500 rounded-md bg-red-100 w-full text-red-600 p-2 my-2">
                                        {{$message}}</p>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" placeholder="apellido">
                                    @error('apellido')
                                    <p class="border border-red-500 rounded-md bg-red-100 w-full text-red-600 p-2 my-2">
                                        {{$message}}</p>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                                    @error('email')
                                    <p class="border border-red-500 rounded-md bg-red-100 w-full text-red-600 p-2 my-2">
                                        {{$message}}</p>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono">
                                    @error('telefono')
                                    <p class="border border-red-500 rounded-md bg-red-100 w-full text-red-600 p-2 my-2">
                                        {{$message}}</p>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                                        placeholder="Contraseña">
                                    @error('contrasena')
                                    <p class="border border-red-500 rounded-md bg-red-100 w-full text-red-600 p-2 my-2">
                                        {{$message}}</p>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2"
                                        placeholder="Confirmar Contraseña">
                                    @error('contrasena2')
                                    <p class="border border-red-500 rounded-md bg-red-100 w-full text-red-600 p-2 my-2">
                                        {{$message}}</p>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nacionalidad"
                                        placeholder="Nacionalidad">
                                    @error('nacionalidad')
                                    <p class="border border-red-500 rounded-md bg-red-100 w-full text-red-600 p-2 my-2">
                                        {{$message}}</p>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block mb-3"
                                    style="color:white; background-color: #1cc88a; font-weight:600">Registrarme</button>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <a type="button" href="login" class="btn linkColor"
                                style="cursor:pointer; color:#1cc88a; font-weight:640">Ya tengo una cuenta</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Image of the ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHgUV.png)

Comment: You need to have a post in one of your routes e.g  Route::post('/registerStore', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'store'])->name('register.store.usu');

Answer (score 2):

You are submitting form using the `post` method

```
<form action="{{ route('register.store.usu') }}" method="post">
```

But in Route you are using `Route::get`

you need to change it to `Route::post` -

```
Route::post('/registerStore', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'store'])->name('register.store.usu');
```

Comment: Sorry idk why, but i thought tat i had to "catch" the method "post" using the "get" one, thank u so much

Comment: the get method will get the form that the user needs to fill out and then the post method will submit that data to the database. It's a simple logic (:

Answer (score 1):

You cant run a create or store because your routes are set to GET in your web.php, change them to

```
Route::post('/registerCreate', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'create'])->name('register.create');

Route::post('/registerStore', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'store'])->name('register.store.usu');
```

And I recommend reading up on some [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x)

Comment: Sorry idk why, but i thought tat i had to "catch" the method "post" using the "get" one, thank u so much

Comment: if he follows the laravel way, then `create` should be `get` and `store` should be `post`